# REST API returning no response

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I created a new REST API which is a PUT method.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Place/Info", Method = "PUT", 
             BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
Info SavePlaceInfo(Info inf);
```

I'm passing  `{}` I'm expecting some error but getting 0 response.

What could be the reason.

Comment: Probably `SavePlaceInfo` was called with `null`. What should be the behaviour in this case?

Comment: if null it should set `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError` and return 500 Internal Server error. But I'm receiving 0 Response or No Response

Comment: How does SavePlaceInfo's body looks like? What do you see when you debug the server?

Comment: `[DataContract] [Serializable]
public class Info : PlaceException
{
 [DataMember]
 public string Id { set; get; }
 [DataMember]
  public string BaseId { set; get; }
  [DataMember]
  public string Status { set; get; }
  [DataMember]
  public DateTime CreatedDate { set; get; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    public class PlaceException
    {
    [DataMember]
     public bool APISuccess { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Message { set; get; }
    DataMember]
     public Exception PlaceException { set; get; }
    }`

Comment: While debugging everything works as expected. But not receiving the response.

Comment: You wrote the `Info` body instead of `SavePlaceInfo()` body... Please add SavePlaceInfo`s the body in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to resolve the issue.
The issue was: Json serializer cannot serialize .Net DateTime.MinValue as its kind is of unsepecified.